# How do I remove dynamically added objects from an array with a button associated with each object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, javascript-objects

I'm using Angular to build a shopping list app. I have two pre-created lists, each with two and three pre-created items respectively for testing purposes. Of course eventually there will be no pre-created items or lists. Everything is to be dynamically added by the user. I was able to get an Add Item button working so you can add a new item to each list.

Here's a pen to play around with it - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WraZEv

```
<body ng-controller="notepadController as notepad">
    <header ng-repeat="list in notepad.lists">
        <div>Delete list</div>
        <h1>{{list.name}}</h1>
    </header>
    <div ng-repeat="list in notepad.lists" class="shoppingList" ng-controller="ItemController as itemCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in list.items">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">
                    {{item.name}}
                </label>
                <form name="removeItemForm" ng-submit="itemCtrl.removeItem(list)">
                    <input type="submit" value="Remove Item">
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form name="itemForm" ng-submit="itemCtrl.addItem(list)">
            <input type="text" ng-model="itemCtrl.item.name">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Item">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

The Javascript is:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('notepadApp', []);

var shoppingLists = [
    {
        name: 'groceries',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'milk',
                checked: false
            },
            {
                name: 'eggs',
                checked: false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'cvs',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'pills',
                checked: false
            },
            {
                name: 'cotton balls',
                checked: false
            },
            {
                name: 'cigs',
                checked: false
            }
        ]
    }
];

app.controller('notepadController', function(){
    this.lists = shoppingLists;
});

app.controller('ItemController', function(){
    this.item = {};

    // add new item to a shopping list
    this.addItem = function(list){
        list.items.push(this.item);
        this.item = {};
    };

    // remove an item from a shopping list
    this.removeItem = function(list){
        var listOfItems = [];

        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < list.items.length; i++){
            list.items.splice(list.items[i,1]);
        }
    };
});
})();
```

The Remove Item button removes all items from a list rather than the item it's associated with. I realize why it's doing this, but I can't figure out how to get the index of the item to be removed and have the Remove Item button delete only that one.

Comment: `.splice` will need 2 arguments. First is `index` second is `number of items to be removed`

Comment: @Rayon Dabre Corrected

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ffa5jw42/

Comment: @RayonDabre you should post as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about it a little bit. You have two controllers. One contains the list, and the other contains the logic for the item.

First of all, if you want to modify the `list`, the functions that modify it should live in the same controller that the `list` lives in.

Currently you're stuck passing the **entire list** because of the way you've set up the controllers. I think you're starting to see what's going wrong with this approach.

Let's start with the repeater

```
ng-repeat="item in list"
```

This gives you the `item`, this is what you want to pass in the function.

Just like how you access the `item` to output the `name` of it, you can use that to pass into your `removeItem`.

```
<form name="removeItemForm" ng-submit="notepad.removeItem(item)">
  <input type="submit" value="Remove Item">
</form>
```

You'll want `removeItem` to live in the same controller where your list lives. (notice I changed `itemCtrl.removeItem` to `notepad.removeItem`.

In `notepadController`:

```
this.removeItem = function(item){
  var index = this.list.indexOf(item);
  if (index > -1) {
    this.list.splice(index, 1); // remove the item
  }
};
```

`ng-repeat` also let's you use a variable called `$index`, you could also use this to provide the `index` you want to remove from the `list`:

```
ng-submit="notpad.removeItem($index)
```

and then the method would look like

```
this.removeItem = function(index) {
  this.list.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: I had to modify your solutions. For the first one, I had to pass both `list` and `item` in the function. I also had to remove `this.` I added `items` to `list` as well so that it reads `list.items.indexOf(item)` and `list.items.splice`

Comment: For the second solution I had to remove `this.` plus pass both `list` and `index` (and passed `list` and `$index` in the ng-submit attribute). I also added `items` here as well - `list.items.splice`

Comment: Good explanation of the approach and concept though